# How can I determine this function?

Tags: functions

If i know that$$ f(3)-f(-1/2) = 7$$ and $$ f(2)-f(1/2) = 3 $$ and $$f(3/2)-f(-2) =7$$ How can I determine the function?

Comment: Even if these equations allowed you to determine $f(x)$ at these six locations (they can't), that is still only six locations out of infinitely many; so there is not nearly enough information.

Comment: You can’t, without more information. Judging by those numbers, though, I suspect that $f$ is supposed to be a linear function, in which case you can at least pin down some information about $f$; is that the case?

Comment: You need more information (such as smoothness and others) about $f$ to determine it by the above equations.

Comment: Your numbers are consistent with $f'(x)=\frac12$, but also with many other more complicated expressions

Comment: Where'd you get this problem?  There' not enough info to determine the function.

Answer (score 1):

$$
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
110004 & \quad x = -2 \\
68 & \quad x = -\frac{1}{2} \\
4 & \quad x = \frac{1}{2} \\
110011 & \quad x = \frac{3}{2} \\
7 & \quad x = 2 \\
75 & \quad x = 3 \\
0 & \quad x\neq-2,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2},2,3
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

Comment: Could you explain this?, I don't get it.

Comment: Look at the given information by Veritas.  My function satisfies  those criteria.

Comment: Got it!!  You could have multiple such combinations

Answer (score 0):

One such function would be any linear function of the form 
$$f(x)=2x+c.$$
This comes from observing that the average rate of change (think slope) on each interval is constant,
$$\frac{f(b_i)-f(a_i)}{b_i-a_i}=\frac{7}{3-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{3}{2-\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}=\frac{7}{\frac{3}{2}-(-2)}=2.$$
My guess is that you are being prodded to answer $f(x)=2x+c,\,c\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that f(x) = 2x could satisfy this but I wonder there are a lot more functions that can satisfy this if we work out!!

Answer (score 0):

$$f(3) - f(-1/2) = f(3/2)-f(2)$$ this gets you $f(7/2) = 7 $ and you also know that $f(3/2) = 3$. And by substituting $f(3/2) = 3 $ you can also get $f(-2) = -4$I agree with the others that there is information missing and I made some assumptions about the function at hand, but a possible answer is $f(x) = 2x$